# Getting wrong output when deploy on server :Getting the video detail between two dates

Tags: java, mongodb, date, video

In my project which is based on spring with mongodb.When i try to get the video of any particular date(17-05-2014) then i get all video of that date(17-05-2014) alongwith some video from next date(18-05-2014) and when i try to fetch the video of  next date(18-05-2014) then those video which is get in previous date(17-05-2014) are not come in this time.
 The code of query is:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String frd="11082013"
c.setTime(sdf.parse(frd));
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //getting the date in the above format with above hr,min and sec.
Date start = c.getTime();

String td= "11082013";
c.setTime(sdf.parse(td));
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
Date end = c.getTime();

    //creating a query for fatch all video from mongodb on the basis of starting and      ending date
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query query = new org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query().addCriteria(Criteria
        .where("creationTime.logtime").gte(start).lte(end));
    //sorting data on the basis of logtime in ascending order
    query.sort().on("creationTime.logtime", Order.ASCENDING);


    //Getting the Video data in the form of list on the basis of above query and sorting from video collection
    List<Video> videos  = mongoTemplate.find(query, Video.class, "video");
```

and the mongodb structure is like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"),
"_class" : "Video",
"videoid" : "2666210586001",
"title" : "Trial1",
"desc" : "",
"creationTime" : {
     "logtime" : ISODate("2013-09-12T08:39:07.227Z"),
     "logtimeStr" : "12-09-2013 02:09:07",
     "day" : 12,
     "month" : 9,
     "year" : 2013,
     "hour" : 14,
     "min" : 9,
     "second" : 7
},
"updatetime" : {
     "logtime" : ISODate("2013-09-12T08:39:07.227Z"),
     "logtimeStr" : "12-09-2013 02:09:07",
     "day" : 12,
     "month" : 9,
     "year" : 2013,
     "hour" : 14,
     "min" : 9,
     "second" : 7
},
 "userName" : "ABC",
 "userId" : "xxxx"
```

**This problem is not create on localhost(windows) But When we deploy on Server(linux) then this problem is created**

If any more data required then please comment

```
 **I scan the output report thoroughly and found that it gives report from 6 am of starting date and before 6 am of next day of ending date **
```

Answer (score 0):

Date fields in MongoDB include the timezone information, so if you want to search by general day ranges you need to account for this. Your current searches are based on dates that don't include time zone offsets.

A simple approach would be to save dates at the required granularity for comparison using a format that will sort correctly, e.g. as strings with `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: Thank you for your response but when we try to keep, Date Format as yyyy-mm-dd then it is not even working on localhost i.e. no record is coming.